# Exo. 29:1 - Difference between לֶחֶם מַצּוֹת, חַלֹּת מַצֹּת, and רְקִיקֵי מַצּוֹת?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, torah

In [Exo. 29:2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Exo&c=29&v=2&t=KJV#s=t_conc_79002), the Hebrew text states,

> וְלֶחֶם מַצּוֹת וְחַלֹּת מַצֹּת בְּלוּלֹת בַּשֶּׁמֶן וּרְקִיקֵי מַצּוֹת מְשֻׁחִים בַּשָּׁמֶן סֹלֶת חִטִּים תַּעֲשֶׂה אֹתָם

What is the difference between the objects identified by the following three phrases:

- לֶחֶם מַצּוֹת
- חַלֹּת מַצֹּת
- רְקִיקֵי מַצּוֹת

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Rashi who quotes the Talmud (Menahot 78a), Exodus 29:2 is referring to three different types of מַצׇּה:

לֶחֶם מַצּוֹת - Scalded (unleavened) dough (רבוכה)
חַלֹּת מַצֹּת - Unleavened loaves
רְקִיקֵי מַצּוֹת - Unleavened wafers

Moses put equal amounts of oil into all three types of matzah, and ten loaves of each type were brought during the offering.

While Rashi's matzah explanation is a bit thin (no pun intended), it does give us a good place to get started.  For those of you who have made your own matzah, you might recall that it starts with kneading dough much in the same way as when you make bread.  It starts off with pieces of unleavened dough like this:

[image]

If you flatten this dough out a bit more, you will end up with unleavened loaves.  And if you roll the dough very flat, you will end up with pieces of matzah resembling wafers.  Here is a picture of what Shmura ("guarded") matzah looks like after it has been baked:

[image]

I welcome comments if anyone can find more definitive references to include.  I gave a cursory glance to מִשְׁנׇה מַסֶּכֶת מְנׇחוֹת but did not see anything explicitly mentioned about the three different types of matzah in Exodus 29:2.